# Active Long Range RFID system for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, rfid

I have bought those cards: [UHPPOTE 2.4Ghz RFID Active Card for Long Distance Range Reader Vehicle Parking System](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01LYO1NUV/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza). I need to buy certain RFID readers to be able to read data from those cards and work with raspberry pi. They work on high frequency and I'm not sure if the reader also need to run on the same frequency or it could be different. I need to be able to read from 4+ meters.

Currently I use RFID-RC522 reader with passive cards on raspberry pi running some python script which works but I need something to work on distance. Can someone tell me if there is any reader for those cards and raspberry pi or if there is any system to implement that will work on Raspbian (not windows IoT) and will work for 4+ meters?

Would those: [UHPPOTE 2.4Ghz Active Direction Long Range 25m RFID Card RS485 Reader For Car Parking](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01LS2I604/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza) . Work with raspberry pi?  How would I connect it?

Answer (score 1):

There is one company that deals with this type of issues. Fully supports raspberry pi and frequency of 2.4GHz with active technology.

You can find more at: [Empress EM02](http://www.hk-rfid.com/active-rfid-reader)

Note that they are quite expensive solution.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.